# Unable to load solution after upgrading to Xamarin Studio 6

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I recently upgraded Xamarin Studio to the latest version, and now I am unable to load my solution!

Upon opening the solution, the below error is displayed:

[image]

I have looked into the logs, and I see the following:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Already bound to project
```

Has anyone seen a similar error, or does anyone have a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error appear to be associated with the following Xamarin bug report:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41565

If you are able to try the following workaround, it should allow you to open the project.

1. Back up the solution
2. Open each .csproj file associated with an extension (such as WatchKit or Today)
3. Find the section "ProjectTypeGuids"
4. Remove the key "FEACFBD2-3405-455C-9665-78FE426C6842"
5. Save the file
6. Attempt to open solution

This should solve it for iOS

This also appears to impact Android projects which contain bindings. For example:

Given a test project (Test.csproj) with two ProjectTypesGUID: {EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF} and {10368E6C-D01B-4462-8E8B-01FC667A7035} the project will fail to load. This is because the first ID corresponds to a regular Android project. The second one is for an Android Binding library project. The problem can be solved by removing the {EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF} GUID from the .csproj

Fixing the issue for Android is similar to above. If the project contains both ProjectTypesGUID: {EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF} and {10368E6C-D01B-4462-8E8B-01FC667A7035} then do the steps below

1. Back the solution up
2. Open the .csproj file
3. Find the section "ProjectTypeGuids"
4. Remove the key "EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF"
5. Save the file
6. Attempt to open solution

Thanks!

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That was it! I had to cycle through each extension project, but it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Got the same problem but this didn't help. Now I also get an warning "Error while trying to load the project '/(...).ios.csproj': Project does not support framework 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0'"

Comment: Which project did you remove the GUID from? Was it only the extension projects? You should be able to add the GUID back again to the non-extension projects and load the solution.

Comment: I have same problem. I removed {FEACFBD2-3405-455C-9665-78FE426C6842} from .IOS.csproj file. Then occur message Superwayne's.

Comment: My xamarin project was made at windows, I copy to Mac. But Couldn't open same error. I solute with doing this. Open solution from windows visual studio. and right click solution then open xxmanager(i don't know english menu name, short cut maybe "o") and check build IOS.

Answer (score 0):

My xamarin project was made at windows, I copy to Mac. But Couldn't open same error. I solute with doing this. Open solution from windows visual studio. and right click solution then open xxmanager(i don't know english menu name, short cut maybe "o") and check build IOS. and copy to all solutions and project files to MAC. Then retry open solution. good luck

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing this issue for hours. It started suddenly when Xamarin.iOS was giving issues due to lack of reference.

I tried the solutions here including removing the guid in Project Build but nothing worked.

To fix this, I realized that Visual Studio for Mac had downloaded an update which I installed and restarted immediately. I then noticed that Visual Studio Xamarin Form iOS component is missing at it states the presence of an update to 12.xxx.

I simply re-downloaded the iOS components (about 550Mb) and I am hoping everything would work fine.